# SQL IF inside a Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql, if-statement

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FSmapping] (
    @runID as bigInt,
    @TypMap as char(1)
    )

RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN


IF (@TypMap ='C')
BEGIN
SELECT b.[A/C],g.accountNumber, b.[Process], g.[endingBalanceLC], g.beginningBalanceLC
FROM table1 g
LEFT JOIN  table2  b ON b.[Acc2]=g.Account_Synt
where RunID = @runID
END
```

I am trying to implement a table function in SQL. Basically it should have 3 more `IF`s and the only thing that's going to switch is the table2, from table2-4 based on inputs C I R S. The error is the `IF` statement, I know that something is missing, I am having a hard time implementing some sort of a switch function with table as a return value. The Select works flawlessly without the IF syntax, it also says errors on the two variables inside the IF

> Must declare the scalar variable runID and TypMap

Comment: You’ll need a [multi statement table valued function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-creating-a-multi-statement-table-valued-function)

Comment: Aside: If the results are compatible you could return `select ... from Table1 where ... and @TypMap = 'C' union all select ... from Table2 where ... and @TypMap = 'I' union all ...;`. The column names will always come from the first query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your query as multi-statement table-valued functions so your function has to like as below:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FSmapping] (
    @runID as bigInt,
    @TypMap as char(1)
    )
RETURNS @Table1JoinTable2 
TABLE (
--table definition here 
Col1 VARCHAR(10)
)
AS
BEGIN
IF (@TypMap ='C')
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @Table1JoinTable2 
SELECT @TypMap
--Put select query SELECT b.[A/C],g.accountNumber, b.[Process], g.[endingBalanceLC], g.beginningBalanceLC
--FROM table1 g
--LEFT JOIN  table2  b ON b.[Acc2]=g.Account_Synt
--where RunID = @runID
END
IF (@TypMap ='I')
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @Table1JoinTable2 
SELECT @TypMap
--Put your select query
END
IF (@TypMap ='I')
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @Table1JoinTable2 
SELECT @TypMap
--Put your select query
END
IF (@TypMap ='R')
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @Table1JoinTable2 
SELECT @TypMap
--Put your select query
END
IF (@TypMap ='S')
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @Table1JoinTable2 
SELECT @TypMap
--Put your select query
END
RETURN
END
```

Comment: Thank you man, I had to delete the SELECT @TypMap tho, but otherwise it works flawlessly :)  bless you

Answer (score 0):

If TypMap does not come C, what will the function return?

i think u need 'ELSE'.

```
IF Boolean_expression
BEGIN
    -- Statement block executes when the Boolean expression is TRUE
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    -- Statement block executes when the Boolean expression is FALSE
END
```

Comment: No no, the IF doesn't need it, my boss had IFs which I tried to work with with no ELSEs